# Django Ajax Post Request Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am working on sending a POST request to Django using Ajax.

Here is my ajax code:

```
$("#submitdata").click(function(){
values = {
"tmode": tmode,
"fmode": fmode,
"t_cool": t_cool,
"t_heat": t_heat,
"hold": hold
};
var jsonText = JSON.stringify(values);
$.ajax({
    url: "/submitdata/",
    type: 'POST',
    data: jsonText,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data){
        alert("Inside success function");
        alert(data.tmode);
    },
    /*complete:function(){
        console.log('complete');
    },*/
    error:function(){
        alert("error");        }
});       });
```

Here is my view:

```
@login_required
def submitvalues(request):
#context = RequestContext(request)
if request.POST:
    jsonvalues = json.loads(request.raw_post_data)
    print json.dumps(jsonvalues)
    #temp = jsonvalues["temp"]
    tmode = jsonvalues['tmode']
    fmode = jsonvalues['fmode']
    t_cool = '65'
    t_heat = '75'
    hold = jsonvalues['hold']
    if jsonvalues.__contains__('t_cool')>=1:
        t_cool = jsonvalues['t_cool']
    if jsonvalues.__contains__('t_heat')>=1:
        t_heat = jsonvalues['t_heat']
    jsonresult = {
                      'tmode':tmode,
                      'fmode':fmode,
                      't_cool':t_cool,
                      't_heat':t_heat,
                      'hold':hold,
                      }
    '''return render_to_response('wifithermostat_3m50/wifithermo3m50.html',
        {'tmode':tmode,'fmode':fmode,'t_cool':t_cool,'t_heat':t_heat,'hold':hold,
         },
        context)'''
    if request.is_ajax()== True:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(jsonresult),mimetype='application/json')
```

I am getting the values in my view. But the response doesn't succeed. I am just trying to get the same data back in essence. But I don't see any success message. Can you guide me as to where I am going wrong?

First of all the alert message from the error section of the ajax function pops up even before the view function is accessed. Also, it never gets to the success part of the ajax call.

I am getting Broken Pipe Error in the runserver console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 284, in  run
self.finish_response()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 324, in finish_response
self.write(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 403, in write
self.send_headers()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 467, in send_headers
self.send_preamble()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 385, in send_preamble
'Date: %s\r\n' % http_date()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
self.flush()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

This ajax call works fine if I don't define it within the `.click(function() {});`
I am sending POST request with a normal click function. Why can't I do it within the click attribute?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Look for django errors in the output to your `runserver` command, or for javascript errors in your javascript console in the browser.

Comment: @SohanJain: I have edited the question with the error I am getting. Glad if you can help with this issue. I am new to Django and having a hard time correcting this issue.

Comment: The broken pipe message in your server can usually be ignored. Just kill the server and restart it. If you're getting an error before the server is actually being hit (verify that in your runserver output there's no call to /submitdata/), then the problem might be on the javascript side. Modify your error callback like so : `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); }` so you're printing out what your actual error is. Note that it's easier to use console.log than alerts. (press f12 if using Chrome to bring up the console)

Comment: Tried the console logging. It just says 'error', against textStatus, errorThrown is an empty string, and the jqXHR is a bunch of functions.

Comment: It sounds like a JS issue, since you said it popup error even before view got called.

Comment: @JerryMeng @sohan-jain It sure seems like a js issue. Am I missing something here? The ajax call works fine when defined as a simple function with `settimeout`. It doesn't work when I put it inside of `.click` of a button.

Comment: well, without actual working environment it is hard to debug. Would you also to switch you ajax to some other trigger event? (other than click). Or at least on different element you want to click. I just want to know is that about 'click' or or it cannot work with any trigger event.

Comment: It doesn't work with any click event. I tried just triggering the function mentioned, on click of a `<div>` tag.

Comment: well, do you mind try to trigger it on other event, like .blur, .change() or similar? I am just curious. And what is the version of jquery you are using?

Answer (score 0):

@jerry-meng : It did not work with any trigger event. I am not sure why.

But the solution to my issue was to prevent the default action that happens on pressing the button.

Modified code:

```
$( "#submitthermostatdata" ).click(function(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
values = {
        "tmode": tmode,
        "fmode": fmode,
        "t_cool": t_cool,
        "t_heat": t_heat,
        "hold": hold
        };
var jsonText = JSON.stringify(values);
console.log(jsonText);
$.ajax({
      url : '/submitdata3m50/',
      type: 'POST',
      data: jsonText,
      dataType: 'json',
      success : function(data) {
        var testinggg = $.parseJSON(data.tmode);
        alert(testinggg);
        alert("testing");
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert("something really wrong");
      }
     }); });
```

Comment: For the button bind with this function, do you have type = 'submit' on it? If it is, it may reasonable to use evt.preventDefault(), but I don't understand why it doesn't work for div. Anyway, as long as you have the fix, it is enough for now.

Comment: I had 'submit' as the button type initially, but then changed it to 'button' type. I am not sure why preventDefault() worked as a solution! I am puzzled with this issue for the past 3 hours. It would be great to know a reason!

Answer (score 0):

If your button is e.g. inside a form, then the default action will be to reload the page, which will interrupt the post thus giving you a broken pipe. 
By adding preventDefault you prevent this reload.